# Semi Transparent ViewController over another ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to display a `UIViewController` over a previous `UIViewController`. I would like it to maintain a semi transparent background with the blurred part being the previous `ViewController`. This also has to be done in code as I will be using a taps action to transition.

I am looking for an answer that uses Swift. Also, in the answer, please specify where the code is supposed to go. (In the taps action, the first `ViewController` or the second `ViewController`.)

Note: I have already searched this question and tried several suggestions, however they all just bring up a second `ViewController` with a colored background.

Thanks in advance.